# Dimensions of LSTM variant in Deep Mind's Differentiable Neural Computer (DNC)

Tags: machine-learning, lstm

I'm trying to implement Deep Mind's DNC - [Nature paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/nature20101)- with PyTorch 0.4.0.

When implementing the variant of LSTM they used I encountered some troubles with dimensions.
To simplify suppose BATCH=1.

The equations they list in the paper are these:
[image: LSTM variant used by DNC]

where `[x;h]` means a concatenation of `x` and `h` into one single vector, and `i`, `f` and `o` are column vectors.

My question is about how the state `s_t` is computed. 
The second addendum is obtained by multiplying `i` with a column vector and so the result is either a scalar (transpose `i` first, then do scalar product) or wrong (two column vectors multiplied).
**So the state results in a single scalar...**

With the same reasoning the hidden state `h_t` is a scalar too, but it has to be a column vector.

Obviously I'm wrong somewhere, but I can't figure out where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at [Wikipedia LSTM Article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_short-term_memory) I think I figured it out.

This is the formal implementation of standard LSTM found in the article:
[image]

The `circle` represents element-by-element product.

By using this product in the corresponding parts of DNC equations (`s_t` and `o_t`) the dimensions work.